# JAVA - MultiMaps and entryset()

Tags: java, data-structures, collections, dictionary, synchronization

A hopefully quick question:

I'm planning to build a MultiMap style structure, internally structured with a Map> structure, and overriding the methods to redirect in an appropriate way to the inner map and lists (so this behaves as a multiMap to the user).  of course, there will be a few additional features possible, particularly if I were to so a version structured as Map> or Map>, and I may well do that after I get the List version working.

My concern is the entrySet() and similar methods: how can I override these to use the same internal data and propagate through the remove methods?

My suspicion is that these sets are built with their remove function redirecting to the remove function of the map, so that provided I implement the remove function of my MultiMap it will behave.  Can anyone confirm this?

Also some static functions in Collections for Maps worry me.  How does the Collections class generate the unmodifiable or synchronised forms and is there a way to ensure my MultiMap is compatible with this?

Answer (score 1):

I guess that depends on how you will create your multimap.

I did something similar and basicly created a MultiMap as a Map where a Collection is the value.
By just using a  map internally my MultiMap is a normal Map and all the utils basicily  just keep working.

```
public class MultiMap<K, V, T extends Collection<V>> implements Map<K, T>
```

Comment: Interesting, but I was looking to keep the structure internal to make it truely behave like a Map of V, without any visibility of the Collection other than a List<V> getAll(Key k) function. Normally I wouldn't even use the entrySet() function and this is a personal library but I do want to do this properly so I don't forget in a few years time. I suppose I could always override entrySet to throw an UnsupportedException or similar but it would feel like cheating.

Comment: i did that too by extending the multimap and hiding implementation: public class MultiListMap<K,V> extends MultiMap<K,V, List<V>>, users can then just say MultiListMap<String,Difference> differences = new MultiListMap<String, Difference>()

Comment: An interesting approach.  I'll have a play around with that thought tonight and see what happens.  The problem still remains for any functions that are supposed to return a Collection that links to the underlying data structure.  How do we make our Multimap return such a Set / Collection without it either returning a set of Collections or returning a Set that doesn't modify the Map?

Comment: I am not sure i understand what you mean by 'a Collection that links to the underlying data structure' my wrapped map has all values stored as Collections so i just can return it and write things like List<Difference> valuesForKey = differences.get(key);

Comment: Look at the APIs for getEntrySet().  It is supposed to return a collection backed by the underlying collection which makes it possible to remove elements from the returned Set and it modifies your Map

Comment: I read the API and now i see what you mean. i just do public Set<Entry<K, T>> entrySet() {
        return map.entrySet();
    } and seems to furfill most parts of the contract. Its not fully tested becuase its something i only use myself mostly though.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using an existing Multimap rather than implementing a new one ?

Have a look at [Google Guava Multimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v12.0/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) for example, and at [Multimaps](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v12.0/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html) for static utility methods...